# pre-increment and post-increment in PHP

Tags: java, php, javascript

the result of the following statement should give 9 : (using java or js or c++)

```
i = 1;
i += ++i + i++ + ++i;
//i = 9 now
```

but in php

the same statements will give 12 ?!

```
$i = 1;
$i +=  ++$i + $i++ + ++$i;
echo $i;
```

is this a bug or can anyone explain why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is "because it's PHP". And PHP doesn't make guarantees about that type of statement (incidentally, neither does C).

Yes, it could be considered wrong, but it's PHP. See [this "not a bug" bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41373).

Answer (score 7):

Look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php#73550) for a similar example.

Basically this is what happens:

First `++$i` is evaluated. `$i` is now 2.
`$i += 2 + $i++ + ++$i;`

Next, `$i++` is evaluated. `$i` is now 3.
`$i += 2 + 2 + ++$i;`

Next, `++$i` is evaluated. `$i` is now 4.
`$i += 2 + 2 + 4;`

Lastly the sum is computed:
`$i = 4 + 2 + 2 + 4 = 12`

Comment: btw great explanation , but I know how it evaluated but the question is why !. i think we cant rely on PHP with operation like this

Comment: @Ahmad Just don't write code like this and you should be fine.

Comment: @Ahmad: 'Why' is a difficult question to answer with anything other than that they chose to implement it that way.

Answer (score 4):

As per the docs on [Operator Precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

```
// mixing ++ and + produces undefined behavior
$a = 1;
echo ++$a + $a++; // may print 4 or 5
```

So I'm guessing what's happening is:

```
$i +=  ++$i + $i++ + ++$i;
```

Gets translated into

```
$i = (++$i + $i++ + ++$i) + $i;
```

In which case, it would add up to 12.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee as to the order those increments. Why write code that is ambiguous?

Comment: It's not ambiguous. Run it a million times, I guarantee you'll get the same result. It has a very well defined order of increments, it's just not immediately obvious what that order is.

Comment: .. Hence being ambigious - it is not clear from the outset what is being done. Why write code that is not obvious in the first place as to what is being achieved. @Thor84no - Come back to this code as a person that maintains code and try to figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: Don't mix up "ambigous" with "irreproducible". Of course, the result can be reproduced with the same PHP implementation. However, it's still ambigous, because the language spec doesn't define how the PHP processor handles it, so it's up to the implementer of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Java, JS or C++ evaluates this equation like that;

```
i = 1;

i += ++i + i++ + ++i; --> i = i* + ++i + i++ + ++i (i* is 1 all the time)
```

But in PHP:

```
$i = 1;

$i += ++$i + $i++ + ++$i; --> $i = $i* + ++$i + $i++ + ++$i ($i* is calculated after increments, in your situation $i* is 4)
```

Difference is that I think.