# How does php evaluate the expression $x+++$x++?

Tags: php

Please, take a look at the following expression:

```
$x = 20;

echo $x+++$x++; // 41
```

Why is the answer `41` instead of `43`?

Comment: @AlexanderLomia Because `echo $x++;` alone outputs `20`, not `21`.

Comment: Pro tip: avoid obscure cases.

Comment: Because `$x++` is a post-incremest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pre-increment and post-increment in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432943/pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-php)

Comment: @u_mulder I see, but again, I don't understand why it's not `20 + 20`(if + has a highest precedence) or `21 + 21`(if the first ++ has the highest precedence)

Comment: `++` has higher precedence than `+` but why do you think that would result in `21 + 21`?

Comment: Run the code at https://3v4l.org/ and look at the opcode!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Altough I can't find any mention in the PHP docs, I guess PHP evaluates from right, and `++` acts like the same operator in C/C++ (see [inc/dec PHP operator docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php))

So, the expression:

```
$x+++$x++
```

in fact does (evaluated from the right):

1. get the value of x → 20
2. increment the value of x → 21
3. get the value of x → 21
4. increment the value of x → 22
5. sum the values *got* from *1* and *3* → 41

It is worth mentioning, though, that in this case the same results is obtained even if the expression is evaluated from the left.

Comment: Don't guess, `+` is a left associativity operator.

Comment: @u_mulder Associativity only matters if you have several operators of the same precedence in a row. There's only one `+` here.

Answer (score 1):

`$x+++$x++;` is

1. Start getting sum of values
2. **First value** is `$x` (20)
3. Increment `$x`  (now `$x` is 21)
4. **Second value** is `$x` (21)
5. Get sum of **first** and **second** values - `20 + 21 = 41`
6. Increment `$x`  (now `$x` is 22)

Another question to read - [What's the difference between ++$i and $i++ in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756015/whats-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
$x+++$x++
```

is evaluated as

```
($x++) + ($x++)
```

The `$x++` returns the value of the `$x` and then increments it by `1`. So, this:

```
$x = 20;
$y = $x++;
```

You end up with `$y == 20` and `$x == 21`. Now, applying this to your expression:

```
$x = 20;
($x++) + ($x++);
```

We get first `$x++` returned as `20` while incrementing `$x` to 21; and the second `$x++` returned as 21 while incrementing `$x` to 22. So:

```
20 + 21
```

which evaluates to 41, but note that $x is now set to 22.